# Android ListView, with EditText ListItem move to Next

Tags: android-listview, android, listadapter

I have a ListView that has ListItem with EditText. This is to simulate a long Form. Once the user is done entering field, I want the cursor to move to next row, i.e. Next ListItem.

To get the next button, in the ListItem xml, I set the ime option to next:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
```

The form could be long with over 20 items to enter. At a given time only 7 rows are visible. which means  7 ListItem rows will be initialized and reused as "convert view". Just by adding the above ime option, the default implementation would would focus to next until the 7th item and would go back to 1 instead of going to 8th item.

How can I make the next go to next item position instead of going back to 1st?

Comment: It can't do that if the next row hasn't been created yet. You can't transfer focus to a view that doesn't exist. If you have a known, small quantity of items (20 is small enough), then you might be better off having a `ScrollView` with all your `EditText`s inside of it already.

Comment: Thanks @Karakuri, That # of item is unknown, it gets provided dynamically by the server. One alternative I found was to use onEditorAction on the edittext. I wonder if there are other options to do this.

Comment: @Karakuri what if more then 100 items?

Comment: If you can't rely on the number of items, then you may have to rely on the user scrolling the list. I don't any way for focus to be transferred because at some point the next view does not exist and/or is not part of the view hierarchy, which is why Android cycles back around and finds the 1st one again.

Comment: Yes I understand, thats why the approach I am leaning towards is to get the view of next position (current position +1), and requesting focus on the edit text for that row. But I am unable to get the next row. getSelectedView returns null.

Comment: @Karakuri But in scrollview if we have more then 80 views then it shows lint warning.So is it right way to ignore lint warning and use scroll view outside of those views(edittext,textview etc.) or listview is right approach? But if OP use listview then there would be problem of edittext focus as described in question.So which way is right? Please suggest.Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: @user3357771 `getSelectedView` is not useful or relevant here. You can't get the next row or next child of a ListView if that child doesn't exist yet. It won't exist until ListView instantiates it with `getView()` and adds it as a child. If you're thinking to call `getView()` yourself to get that next child, I guarantee this will not work. The only thing I would even attempt is to programmatically scroll the ListView to encourage generation of the next item.

Comment: @GiruBhai This is less about right vs. wrong and more about better vs. worse. I said a known, small quantity, but never gave a number. The OP said 20--I thought this was relative fixed, but it's not. Sorry, there are no concrete answers.

Comment: @Karakuri Thanks for response.Can you look at [Android : Best way to Design long input form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311365/android-best-way-to-design-long-input-form)

Comment: One approach would be to check the current position vs the lastvisible position. if position is equals lastvisible that means you would need to scroll up. You could do it by calling smoothScrollToPosition and setSelection. This will scroll you r list item to the top. So might want to do scroll up by one and use handler to select the last item on the list. There might be a better way to scroll up by one and maintain the selection to the last one.