# How to set focus on dynamically added editext in listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying something similar to this [Android ListView, with EditText ListItem move to Next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343936/android-listview-with-edittext-listitem-move-to-next) Initially one editext will displayed and when user enters the value I am creating a item on Editext.onTextChanged method. After entering the value the,editext is created but the focus is lost the user has to tap again to enter the value.How to set focus on the next editext element in listview ?

Can anyone please explain me where I am going wrong.Any suggestions are really helpful.

thanks

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.testeditext.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
    ListView lv;
    LvAdapter adpter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        lv.setStackFromBottom(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            list.add("1");
        }

        adpter = new LvAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(adpter);
    }

    public class LvAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public LvAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            convertView = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ada, null); // this is your cell

                holder.caption = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText12);
                holder.caption.setTag(position);
                holder.caption.setText(list.get(position).toString());
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            int tag_position = (Integer) holder.caption.getTag();
            holder.caption.setId(tag_position);

            holder.caption.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
                    final int position2 = holder.caption.getId();
                    final EditText Caption = (EditText) holder.caption;
                    if (Caption.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                        //list.set(position2,Integer.parseInt(Caption.getText().toString()));
                        if (position == getCount() - 1) {
                            list.set(position2, Caption.getText().toString());
                            list.add(holder.caption.getText().toString());
                        } else {
                            list.set(position2, Caption.getText().toString());
                            // holder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
                        }

                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else {
                        list.remove(position2);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter some value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        EditText caption;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title is misleading. `How to add editext` is not `How to set focus on the next editext`

Answer (score 1):

So far I can think of one way I would approach this:

First, in the `onTextChanged()` remove focus on the item you just used to create the new one.
Then in `getView()`check if the requested view is the last one and in that case set the focus on it.

You will have to add a boolean field, let's call it `setFocusToLast`.
Once you create the new field and remove focus from the one you used to create it, you will set `setFocusToLast` to `true`.

You will also need to know  when user explicitly requested focus on another element, so you will need to implement `onFocusChanged()` (in which you will reset `setFocusToLast` to false) this just in case the user doesn't want to keep adding fields, but choses to edit an existing one.
If you don't do this, and the users scrolls down so that the last item becomes visible, the focus would move to it.